# Why are contacts used to connect metal to active layers but not poly to active layers?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, layout

In the CMOS layouts that I've seen, metal layers always seem to connect to n+/p+ active regions by using a contact, but poly layers are just laid directly over them. Is there a reason we don't use a contact between the poly and active region?

Comment: *The question is self-explanatory.* Only to those that are familiar with layouting ICs.

Comment: The question is **not** self-explanatory. You need to clarify what you mean by "it" in the phrase "we can't connect it". Contacts? Poly? Metal1? Also clarify what you mean by "active area"....a source/drain region or under the gate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand why we use contacts to connect poly... but we can't connect it [poly] to the active area.

First of all, metal1-poly and metal1-active are perfectly fine as you mention. It's poly-active that doesn't make sense.

The reason is that poly happens to affect the active area when fabricating self-aligned gates. Recall that the active area is where field oxide is removed and implantation can occur, leading to doping of the substrate in those regions. In a self-aligned-poly-gate process, the poly itself acts as a mask creating gaps in the active area's doping, e.g. to create a channel within the substrate:

[image]

Clearly there's no way to make a contact connection between the poly and active area because the portion under the poly is no longer actively implanted.

Second, the poly is deposited directly upon the very thin gate oxide which was grown in a previous step. The gate oxide growth process does not allow for the provision of a contact to be created; to do so would require an extra field mask step, placement of a metal contact, and then some way of growing poly atop that heterogeneous structure, for dubious benefit (because of the reasons outlined in earlier parts of the post).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why we use contacts to connect poly to metal1 or to gnd/vcc

GND and VCC are (usually) **electrical supply lines** and they have **nothing** to do with the internal layers like Poly and Metal1.

I do not fully understand your question. Of all the IC processes that I worked on, Contacts **are** used to connect Metal1 to poly or Metal1 to Active.

Maybe you're using a process where things are different. Consult the design manual to see what you can do and what not.

> Is it because a channel is formed and it would conduct?

Where is normally a channel formed? Hint: the structure is called "MOS".

Comment: I don't understand your statement that GND and VCC have "nothing to do with...Poly and Metal1". How do we get the power supply and ground connections to the transistors if we can't use Metal1? Why can't we connect power or ground to poly?